# Assign a proper wp_nav_menu() container

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to change the `wp_nav_menu()` container to `<aside>` tag, but it does not work. The other tags (`<nav>` for example) has no problem.

Example:

```
<?php 
    wp_nav_menu(['theme_location' => 'left_menu',
                 'container' => 'aside',
                 'menu_class' => 'sidebar'
                ]);
?>
```

Results in:

```
<ul id="menu-menu-2" class="sidebar">
    <li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36"><a href="">Calculator</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-35"><a href="">Choose menu</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-34"><a href="">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please provide code examples of what you have done - what you get in return and what exactly you are after. This question as it currently stands is far too vague, cheers :)

Comment: @simonpollard I represented the code that I had written and result of it. I think it's completely clear, and I had received the answer that I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because only the tags `div` and `nav` can be used as menu containers in WordPress. Don't ask me why. It is the way WordPress is designed. This has not been documented anywhere in the codex. We get to know this if we go through the [WordPress codebase](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L350).

But we can override this by using the filter [`wp_nav_menu_container_allowedtags`](http://hookr.io/4.5/filters/wp_nav_menu_container_allowedtags/). The following code should help you achieve this.

```
// Override the default allowed tags in wp_nav_menu()

function custom_nav_menu_container_allowedtags( $allowed_tags ) {
    $allowed_tags[] = 'aside';
    return $allowed_tags;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_container_allowedtags', 'custom_nav_menu_container_allowedtags' );
```